# Maven Dependancy Refereing old Poi Version

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, classpath, apache-poi

I am using Apache Poi version 3.8 in my POM. But it is still downloading poi-3.2 along with poi-3.8 as (may be) due to some internal dependency. The strange behavior for me is My project using poi-3.2 when even I have mentioned 3.8 version in POM. I have Googled a lot for the same, but found myself unlucky.
Here is my POM entry :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.8</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

I have checked the poi jar my project using in classpath by the code:

```
    ClassLoader classloader =
               org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.class.getClassLoader();
            URL res = classloader.getResource(
                         "org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem.class");
            String path = res.getPath();
            System.out.println("Core POI came from " + path);
```

This prints :

```
Core POI came from file:/D:/Software/Softwares/apache-tomcat-6.0.33/webapps/scd-web/WEB-INF/lib/poi-3.2.jar!/org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem.class
```

There is a poi-3.8.jar in same folder but classpath picking up 3.2.

**My question is :**
What should I do to so that My project uses poi-3.8.jar instead of poi-3.2.jar.

Many Thanks !!

**Edited:**
Output of `mvn dependency:tree`

```
 [INFO] Building SCD-common [INFO]    task-segment: [dependency:tree]
 [INFO]
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
 [WARNING] While downloading xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.3.0   This artifact has been relocated to org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.3.0.
 [INFO] [dependency:tree] [INFO] com.idc:scd-common:jar:4.2.0.5 
 [INFO]  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:2.5.6:compile 
 [INFO]  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile 
 [INFO]  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.6:compile 
 [INFO]  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:2.5.6:compile 
 [INFO]  |     \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:2.5.6:compile 
 [INFO]  +- com.idc.worldwide.keystones:service-single-signon-dynamo-api:jar:1.0:compile 
 [INFO]  +- com.idc.worldwide.keystones:service-single-signon-dynamo-database-impl:jar:1.0.3:compile 
 [INFO]  |  +- org.apache:commons-dbcp:jar:1.2.2:compile 
 [INFO]  |  +- org.apache:commons-pool:jar:1.4:compile 
 [INFO]  |  \- com.idc.worldwide.webchannel:sage-core:jar:3.2.0.001:compile 
 [INFO]  |     +- com.idc.webchannel.legacy.sage-dependencies:aspose-slides:jar:1. 0:compile 
 [INFO]  |     +- com.servlets:cos:jar:09May2002:compile
 [INFO]  |     +- com.sun:jai_codec:jar:1.1.3:compile 
 [INFO]  |     +- com.sun:jai_core:jar:1.1.3:compile 
 [INFO]  |     +- com.verity:k2:jar:5.00.3177.0:compile 
 [INFO]  |     +- org.apache:poi:jar:3.2:compile 
 [INFO]  |     +- org.apache:poi_contrib:jar:3.2:compile 
 [INFO]  |     +- org.apache:poi_scratchpad:jar:3.2:compile 
 [INFO]  |     \- org.springframework:spring:jar:2.5.6:compile 
 [INFO]  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile 
 [INFO]  |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile 
 [INFO]  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
```

Comment: what is the output of "mvn dependency:tree"?

Comment: @bowmore: its..

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Reactor build order:
[INFO]   Service contract database
[INFO]   SCD-common
[INFO]   SCD-WEB
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin wit
Downloading:

Comment: You should put that output in the question, not in a comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like

```
org.apache:poi:jar:3.2
```

is a compile dependency of

```
com.idc.worldwide.keystones:service-single-signon-dynamo-database-impl
```

(although I think you may have cut something)

and

```
org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.8
```

is not a dependency (it's not in the dependency tree).

Make sure your `<dependency>` entry is within the `<dependencies>` tag.

Comment: Thanks @bowmore, `org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.8` is also in dependency, As I mentioned whole output is too long to paste here. But I have seen 3.8 is also there.

Comment: it's just no good trying to analyze partial output. If you could upload it elsewhere (pastebin?) and provide a link, that would definitely help

Answer (score 3):

There are [various mvn command](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html) to help solving this issue:

`mvn dependency:analyze-dep-mgt`

will print details about dependency resolving.

`mvn dependency:tree`

will print the dependency tree (very helpful to see dependencies of your dependencies)

[`mvn help:effective-pom`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html)

will print the pom resulting from the merge of your pom hierarchy.

If you don't find any references to poi-3.2 with maven, you can take a look at your classpath in your IDE. Do you add any jar by-passing maven ?

Editing your question with the result of those commands can be useful for us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Run

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

to check which library has a transitive dependency to poi 3.2. You can then exclude it in your pom.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>sample.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>sample-artifactB</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <exclusions>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are mixing normal dependency with plugin dependency, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254356/maven-dependency-management-for-plugin-dependencies) (not too fitting answer).

Use dependency management in the root POM if you have child projects.